# Angular: calling transclude directive function from within the transcluded component

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to create a component which will have a transcluded part, here is an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/vp2dnj65/1/

As you can see when clicking the do button nothing happens.
Is there any way to run transcluded controller function from a component which is placed within the transcluded part.

Here is the HTML:

```
<panel> // trans is the name of the controller of panel
   <button ng-click="trans.do()">do</button> //transcluded part
</panel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achieve that if you manually transclude the element and attach the scope function to it:

```
compile: function(tElement, tAttrs) {
  var parentElement = tElement.parent();
  return function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transclude) {
    transclude(scope.$new(), function(clone) {
      clone.bind('click', function() {
        scope.trans.do();
      })
      parentElement.append(clone);
    });
  };
}
```

as shown in this [tutorial](https://www.accelebrate.com/blog/angularjs-transclusion-part-1/).
see also this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pkcoga80/).

Answer (score 0):

When using `transclude` the inside component is connected to the upper parent (that is not the transcluding parent). In your case I would advise using an event (either `$rootScope` or a service) that will be registered by the `trans` controller and fired by the transcluded component.

Comment: I don't want to use events, and service is a very cupeled solution in my opinion.